# date format cannot convert in data format

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to create an application where it pulls the information from website using python and I am using `datetime` formats.

```
def constructYFURL(ticker,start_date,end_date,freq):
    start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
    end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date,"%Y-%m-%d").date()

    s=ticker.replace("^","%5E")

    if start_date.month-1<10:
        a="0"+str(start_date.month-1)
    else:
        a=str(start_date.month-1)

    # Also the month always has 2 digits
    b=str(start_date.day)

    c=str(start_date.year)

    if end_date.month - 1 < 10:
        d = "0" + str(end_date.month - 1)
    else:
        d = str(end_date.month - 1)

    e=str(end_date.day)

    f=str(end_date.year)

    `enter code here`g=freq

    yfURL = "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?   s="+s+"&a="+a+"&b="+b+"&c="+c+"&d="+d+"&e="+e+"&f="+f+"&g="+g+"&ignore=.csv"
return yfURL


from download import constructYFURL
ticker = "AAPL"
start_date = "2016-01-01"
end_date = " 2017-03-06"
freq = "d"

yfURL = constructYFURL(ticker,start_date,end_date,freq)

print yfURL
```

I am getting a following error saying:

> ValueError: time data ' 2017-03-06' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra leading space in:

```
end_date = " 2017-03-06"
```

remove it and the error you're getting goes away and the program runs

Better formatted code:

```
def constructYFURL(ticker,start_date,end_date,freq):
    start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
    end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date,"%Y-%m-%d").date()

    s=ticker.replace("^","%5E")

    if start_date.month-1<10:
        a="0"+str(start_date.month-1)
    else:
        a=str(start_date.month-1)

    # Also the month always has 2 digits
    b=str(start_date.day)
    c=str(start_date.year)

    if end_date.month - 1 < 10:
        d = "0" + str(end_date.month - 1)
    else:
        d = str(end_date.month - 1)

    e=str(end_date.day)
    f=str(end_date.year)
    g=freq


    yfURL = "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?   s="+s+"&a="+a+"&b="+b+"&c="+c+"&d="+d+"&e="+e+"&f="+f+"&g="+g+"&ignore=.csv"
    return yfURL


ticker = "AAPL"
start_date = "2016-01-01"
end_date = "2017-03-06"
freq = "d"

yfURL = constructYFURL(ticker,start_date,end_date,freq)

print yfURL
```